How to do spectral averaging to get satisfactory results?
I’ve been trying to implement spectral averaging as an experiment to familiarize myself better with FFTs and their uses for the past couple of days.
Until I've hit a wall when I tried to replicate the results explained in this video lecture.
The idea is to average the magnitudes of the Fourier Transforms of several images, and then use this average magnitude with the phase of another image to reconstruct it so that it retains some of the original image’s features.
Basically this lecture is showing the importance/impacts of magnitudes/phases, the first part which is setting the phase to zero can be easily done, but the second part is just too hard, I cant seem to get anything near what he gets in the presentation.
I also face a weird issue, which is if I try to visualize the final reconstructed image using purely its real values, the image is upside down! whereas if I use its magnitude its straight/normal! but lacks details! (even compared to the version where I only use the real values only!). note that the fft is not shifted! so I assume I should be getting the same result as the one using magnitude!
I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong/missing something here, or to get the same level of clarity/details that the professor gets, I need to have lots of images.
I've tried from 5 to 460 images, from purely car images(460), landscapes(28-100), cityscapes(100), and animals(8-100) to a mix of all of them, yet still I don't get anything close to that! by watching the lecture I get the feeling, a few natural images should suffice, however in practice I'm finding it hard to make it happen with a few images. I'm completely clueless here.
Here is what I have tried:

img = cv2.imread('./img/monroe.jpg',0)
w,h = img.shape
fft = np.fft.fftn(img)
magnitude = np.abs(fft)
fft_no_phase = magnitude + 0j
img_no_phase = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(fft_no_phase)).astype(np.uint8)

# lets calculate the phase now and then read a few natural images and use their average of magnitude
# instead of the real magnitude of our image
phase = np.angle(fft)

# read a few images
img_list=[]

# links
# took them from https://awesomewallpapersblog.com/
# Animals images: https://mega.nz/#!f14xCISR!j2rYFXRy9R7IOSHXnLirlYIYD0-rSX-OT6RVzz4R_mU
# Natural images: https://mega.nz/#!LlxGSCoK!ehjymd_pNKiaa9j6zoLpMi4FxnUtXQdXVcbd5P2s5dA
# Cities images: https://mega.nz/#!ehwSxIbT!Fniqo6a5cXJTDI1xFiz2w6jVRkLDvk2FgaPPt6dejF8
# Bing random images: https://mega.nz/#!a4ZGCYaK!Gzo1nb9ZSEcjNHqmWWy4wJAXOhaaAGAV5KnQoUpXrrI
dir = "/cityscapes"

for p in glob.glob(f'{dir}/*.jpg'):
    img_list.append(cv2.imread(p,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    
print(f'images found: {len(img_list)}')

# now lets resize them to the same size as our image
img_list = [cv2.resize(img,dsize=(h,w),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) for img in img_list]

# calculate ffts for each image
fft_list = [np.fft.fft2(im) for im in img_list]

# calculate and average the magnitudes
magnitudes = np.array([np.abs(fft) for fft in fft_list])
magnitudes_average = magnitudes.mean(axis=0)

# add the original phase data to the averaged magnitudes
fft_average_magnitude = magnitudes_average * np.exp(1j+phase)

# now lets get back the image
ift = np.fft.ifft2(fft_average_magnitude)
image_phase_with_avg_magnitude = np.abs(ift).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_real_flipped = ift.real.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_real_corrected = cv2.flip(img_real_flipped,-1)

# see what was used to get the magnitude!
natural_imgs = np.hstack(img_list)

cv2.imshow('img-original', img)
cv2.imshow('natural images', natural_imgs)
cv2.imshow('img-no-phase', img_no_phase)
cv2.imshow('image_phase_with_avg_magnitude', image_phase_with_avg_magnitude)
cv2.imshow('img_real-flipped', img_real_flipped)
cv2.imshow('img_real-corrected', img_real_corrected)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


These are what I get:
Original image:

image phase with avg magnitude:

using image's real value (its flipped)

using image's real values corrected

image with no phase


The following line in your code is incorrect for setting the phase:
# add the original phase data to the averaged magnitudes
fft_average_magnitude = magnitudes_average * np.exp(1j+phase)

It should be:
fft_average_magnitude = magnitudes_average * np.exp(1j*phase)

Notice the multiplication rather than addition.

Thanks a lot. really appreciate it :), it now works even with a random natural image (gets better as the number of images is increased :) by the way do you happen to know why visualizing the real values results in an upside down/flipped image while using the magnitude doesnt? I havent shifted the ffts, so I assume it should have stayed straight regardless of me using the real values or calculating the actual magnitude.

Does that still occur after correcting the problem I identified? I presumed it would eliminate your flipping problem and also eliminate the need to isolate the real component of the inverse fast Fourier transform since the result should no longer be complex. Or are you asking why it occurred before fixing the phase problem?

yes id really appreciate that.
(after your comment, I noticed it was fixed and the flipped version I saw was the one with cv2.flip(-1) which I'd written to correct the previously flipped output. so yeah that was fixed. though I'd still would love to know what really caused it to be flipped previously?

Here are some observations: (1) your incorrect phase setting operation gave all frequency components the same 1 radian phase and scaled amplitudes by $e^{phase}$, which can only result from a complex signal; (2) you can decompose the frequency domain into components from real and imaginary signals, which involves terms relevant to the time reversal DFT property; (3) your amplitude image actually appears to be a superposition of two images, one normal and one reversed, which corresponded to the imaginary and real components, but I'm not sure how to prove which is reversed in general.

Thanks a lot really appreciate it:)
